# writing from a function in a Bash script leaking file descriptors

Tags: bash, unix, ubuntu-10.04, file-descriptor

We have a shell script that is called by cron and runs as root.

This script outputs logging and debug info, and has been failing at one certain point. This point varies based on how much output the script creates (it fails sooner if we enable more debugging output, for example).

However, if the script is called directly, as a user, then it works without a problem.

We have since created a simplified test case which demonstrates the problem.

The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
function log_so () {
  local msg="$1"
  if [ -z "${LOG_FILE}" ] ; then warn_so "It's pointless use log_so() if LOG_FILE variable is undefined!" ; return 1 ; fi
  echo -e "${msg}"
  echo -e "${msg}" >> ${LOG_FILE}
  (
    /bin/true
  )
}


LOG_FILE="/usr/local/bin/log_bla"

linenum=1
while [[ $linenum -lt 2000 ]] ; do
  log_so "short text: $linenum"
  let linenum++
done
```

The highest this has reached is 244 before dying (when called via cron).

Some other searches recommended using a no-op subshell from the function and also calling /bin/true but not only did this not work, the subshell option is not feasible in the main script.

We have also tried changing the file descriptor limit for root, but that did not help, and have tried using both #!/bin/sh and #!/bin/bash for the script.

We are using bash 4.1.5(1)-release on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Any ideas or recommendations for a workaround would be appreciated.

Comment: Unable to duplicate on Fedora 16, GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release, even with a ulimit of 128. Suggest migration to a more specific forum.

Comment: I just learned that this is a bug in bash 4.1 and older that has been corrected in 4.2, and I don't know if upgrading bash is an option for us, so still would like to find a solution for bash 4.1.x if one exists.

Answer (score 1):

What about opening a fd by hand and cleaning it up afterwards? I don't have a bash 4.1 to test with, but it might help.

```
LOG_FILE="/usr/local/bin/log_bla"

exec 9<> "$LOG_FILE"

function log_so () {
    local msg="$1"
    if [ -z "${LOG_FILE}" ] ; then warn_so "It's pointless use log_so() if LOG_FILE variable is undefined!" ; return 1 ; fi
    echo -e "${msg}"
    echo -e "${msg}" >&9
    return 0
}

linenum=1
while [[ $linenum -lt 2000 ]] ; do
  log_so "short text: $linenum"
  let linenum++
done

exec 9>&-
```

Comment: We tried this, and in the 4.1 that we have it does not work. We have a work around for now that involved refactoring to script to remove some of the output and consolidate it. If there is a solution that doesn't require upgrading bash (not an option ATM) and allows more output that would be quite helpful.